# Converting a string of coordinates to an X,Y np array

Tags: python, numpy

Given this string:

```
str="418,368 885,365 953,562 361,569"
```

I'd like to convert it into an np.array like this:

```
np.array ([[418,368], [885,365], [953,562], [361,569]])
```

What's a good way to do this in Python?

So far, I'm stuck here:

```
>>> str="418,368 885,365 953,562 361,569"
>>> result=[x.strip() for x in str.split(' ')]
>>> print (result)
['418,368', '885,365', '953,562', '361,569']
```

I need to somehow convert this to the array I want. I see an `np.fromstring` but not sure how to connect it, and wonder if this path is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert spaces to commas and then split with commas as delimiter. Then, convert to int dtype array and reshape -

```
In [17]: np.array(str.replace(' ',',').split(','),dtype=int).reshape(-1,2)
Out[17]: 
array([[418, 368],
       [885, 365],
       [953, 562],
       [361, 569]])
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
import numpy as np

data = "418,368 885,365 953,562 361,569"
result = np.array([x.strip().split(',') for x in data.split(' ')], dtype=int)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[[418 368]
 [885 365]
 [953 562]
 [361 569]]
```

Comment: I think something is missing (maybe minor). I get a `TypeError: pts data type = 19 is not supported` when I try to pass it onto openCV to draw a polygon.

Comment: Ah yes, needs to be converted to ints. But I wasn't clear on what I wanted to do with the array, so fair enough.